# Why integer division by zero doesn't crash the program compiled with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc

Integer division by zero is undefined and should result floating point exception and this is what happens why I write the following code

```
 int j = 0 ;
 int x = 1 / j;
```

In this case the program just crashes with FPE, but if I won't use variable and will go with literal values like this `int x = 1 / 0;` the the program doesn't crash, but just assigns some random value to `x` ! I tried to detect if `int x = 1 / 0;` really causes a crash by adding custom `SIGFPE` handler, but as I thought it is never invoked during literal zero division, but it does when I store `0` in a variable first. So, it seems that the literal zero division never actually crashes the program( I mean the division itself never happens), so does the compiler(GCC in my case) performs any tricks(e.g. substituting `0` with random number) in this case? or I misunderstood something ?

Comment: Use float, integer division by zero is UB thus compiler is not obligated to raise any signal

Comment: `1 / 0` might not be done at runtime but by the compiler. Its value is undefined.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thank you, I was also thinking about this, but then I run the same executable(without recompiling) and every time got different random values for `x`. So, if `x` is resolved at compile time then I guess the value should be the same for every run

Comment: MS Visual C issues a **compiler** error: *divide or mod by zero*.

Comment: No, undefined is undefined.

Comment: How is this undefined behaviour different from all other undefined behaviours?

Answer (score 3):

> Why integer division by zero doesn't crash the program compiled with gcc?

Well, I think the answer would be: because it can. It can crash. It can not crash.

> or I misunderstood something ?

From [C11 6.5.5p5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p5) (emphasis mine :p) :

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the remainder. In both operations, **if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined**.

[The behavior is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). It is not defined what should happen. It can "crash". It can not crash. It can [spawn nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The program can do anything.

You should write only programs that you *know* how will they behave. If you want your program to "crash", call `abort()`.

> so does the compiler(GCC in my case) performs any tricks(e.g. substituting 0 with random number) in this case?

The only way to know is to inspect the generated assembly code. You could use https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Nice job on the citations.

Answer (score -2):

Since the expression contains division by zero constant, gcc could handle the issue at compile time.

If the division by variable valued 0, the compiler will give the responsibility to the exception handler because the evaluation is unpredictable.